# css Fade out box-shadow on edge

Tags: html, css

for school i need to make a exact replica of a website and im stuck on a part where i need to (i think) add box shadow, but the shadow fades out on the edges and i do not know how to do this myself, so does anyone know how to do this?

i have a field of text and the top and bottom have a border line/shadow and it fades out at the edges.

this is what i need to replicate

my css code:

```
#ReaderSlideshow{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
margin-top: 50px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

my html:

```
<div id="ReaderSlideshow">
    <img src="img/Backarrow.png" alt="Backarrow" width="22px">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.     </p>
    <img src="img/forwardarrow.png" alt="forwardarrow" width="22px">
</div>
```

[image: this is how it is supposed to look like]
[image: This is what i made]

Comment: Please put your code here to show what have you tried so far.

Comment: i edited to post to make my problem more clear it should be understandable what i want to replicate now.

Comment: Hint: `background-image: radial-gradient()` — good luck.

Comment: ok but you cant add a gradient to a border right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```css
hr { 
  display:block;
    border:none;
    color:white;
    height:1px;
    background:black;
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(#000), to(#fff));
}
```

This is using gradient on `hr` element. You can add more prefixes for other browsers but this should work :)

Play with numbers and colors. You will find gradient very powerfull thing in CSS

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to add a **wrapper** div to your DOM and then implement a **radial-gradient** to it.

Note: In your comment you said cannot implement gradient on border; Just for the record, that's not a border, that's a box-shadow implemented on top and bottom of your div.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: content;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,232,234,0.896796218487395) 0%, rgba(174,175,177,1) 100%); /* this line does the trick */
}

#ReaderSlideshow{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #aeafb1, 0px -1px 5px #aeafb1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="ReaderSlideshow">
  <img src="img/Backarrow.png" alt="Backarrow" width="22px">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.     </p>
  <img src="img/forwardarrow.png" alt="forwardarrow" width="22px">
 </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-radial-gradient/) you can find a good explanation on **CSS Radial Gradient**.

And [Here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/) is a **Box Shadow** tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could tell by the image, `#ReaderSlideshow` has a gradient as well as it's border. I was going to suggest pseudo-elements (::before and ::after) but the flex will mess it up, so I had to add a container with padding instead. The container has the gradient of the "borders" and `#ReaderSlideshow` uses another gradient.

I also added a CSS variable in order to be slightly more dynamic.

```css
body {
  --background-color: #e7e8ea;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}

.slideshow-container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;

  background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--background-color) 0%, #dfe0e1 50%, var(--background-color) 100%);
}

#ReaderSlideshow {
  display: flex;
  
  padding: 0.5rem;

  background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--background-color) 0%, #ecedee 50%, var(--background-color) 100%);
}

#ReaderSlideshow > p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#ReaderSlideshow > p {
  margin: 0px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 0px 2rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div id="ReaderSlideshow">
       <img src="img/Backarrow.png" alt="⤆" width="22px">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.     </p>
       <img src="img/forwardarrow.png" alt="⤇" width="22px">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bg {
background-color: blue;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}

.inner{
position: absolute;
margin-left: 200px;
margin-top: 100px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px black;
  box-shadow: 2px 6px 4px -4px black;
}
```

```html
<div class = "bg">
  <div class = "inner">
  </div>
</div>
```